# JavaScript: How can I POST an arbitrary request body to a server?

Tags: javascript, http

Normal, we can send an Ajax request or submit a form to a server, which in the *HTTP request body* would be encoded like this: `name=helloworld&age=123`.

Now our server *only accepts JSON data* as the request body. Is there a way to change the encoding method of the request body in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you attach a code sample?

Comment: @MrROY - you can't change it for forms.  AJAX requests can submit as JSON, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML forms give you three options for encoding the data. `text/plain` is useful only for debugging (and not very useful even when given browser developer tools), and neither of the other two are JSON.

With [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), the encoding is however you encode the data.

[The `send` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) can take a string: You can encode the data in that string however you like.

```
function sendJSON() {
    var data = {
        name: "helloworld",
        age: 123
    };

    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/example/");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(json);
}
```

You can also pass other kinds of data such as a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object (which can include files and will us multipart encoding) but you don't need anything so complex for JSON.